# Exception caught by image resource service The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

```
════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: /data/user/0/com.Freedom.new_chat/cache/file_picker/-vimzzn.jpg
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load
package:flutter/…/services/asset_bundle.dart:228
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync
package:flutter/…/painting/image_provider.dart:675
<asynchronous suspension>
```

Anyone can help me i can provide the codes
i would provide them now but i dont know which one have the error and thanks

now i get this one too

```
    Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "/data/user/0/com.Freedom.new_chat/cache/file_picker/Snapchat-1984491257.jpg")
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#534c4(), name: "/data/user/0/com.Freedom.new_chat/cache/file_picker/Snapchat-1984491257.jpg", scale: 1.0)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

close your emulator and run this command
**flutter clean**
then run this command
**flutter pub get**
Run Your App